# Terraform count to for_each refactor

Tags: terraform

Trying to refactor count to for_each and having hard time with this.

```
local = {
      routes = [
        {
           CIDR = "192.225.0.0/16"
           Name = "rt-1"
         },
         {
           CIDR = "192.225.0.0/16"
           Name = "rt-2"
         },
         {
           CIDR = "192.225.1.0/16"
           Name = "rt-1"
         },
         {
           CIDR = "192.225.1.0/16"
           Name = "rt-2"
        },
        {
           CIDR = "192.225.0.0/16"
           Name = "rt-3"
         }
       ]
    }
Works:
   resource "aws_route" "sample" {    
     count = length(local.routes)
     route_table_id            = local.routes[count.index].Name
    destination_cidr_block    = local.routes[count.index].CIDR
   }

Don't Work:
   resource "aws_route" "sample" {
     for_each = local.routes 
     route_table_id            = local.routes[count.index].Name
     destination_cidr_block    = local.routes[count.index].CIDR
   }
```

Getting this error
The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.

If I change my local to map then it complains about duplicate, any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for_each` meta-argument accepts a map or a set of strings and not list and you are trying to pass a list. You could do something like this:

```
resource "aws_route" "sample" {
   for_each = { for entry in local.routes : "${entry.Name}.${entry.CICR}" => entry }

  route_table_id            = each.value.Name
  destination_cidr_block    = each.value.CIDR
 }
```

Read more on `for_each`: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#basic-syntax

Comment: I tried that but I am getting duplicate object keys, "Two different items produced the key  in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key"